# How to initiate selenium web driver with brave browser using python

Tags: python, selenium, brave-browser

My chromium version is 87.0.4280.88

My brave browser version is 87.0.4280.101

I tried a lot of codes but they didn't work.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\BraveSoftware\Brave- 
Browser\Application\brave.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe', options=option)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\MOHSEN\Desktop\test\Untitled-1.py", line 5, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'options'
```

Comment: You're going to need to supply a lot more detail.

Comment: You will need to add:

Python version, the code you are trying to execute, selenium driver version, and the error you are getting.

Comment: In [this](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/getting_started_with_webdriver/browsers/) list, from selenium's official website. Brave isn't listed here.

Comment: can you put the error and code here?

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

To initiate a [brave](/questions/tagged/brave) *Browsing Session* using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  option.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\brave.exe'
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe', options=option)
  driver.get("https://www.google.com")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Brave]

Comment: I tried that and got this message

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\MOHSEN\Desktop\test\Untitled-1.py", line 5, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'options'